# How to build Derived columns transformation dynamically in Azure Data Factory - Mapping Data Flow?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

Is it possible to build derived columns transformation dynamically in Azure data factory Data Flow?

Say, I have two files. File 1 with 4 columns and File 2 with 13 columns.
My simple transformation flow looks like this:

[image]

I will be reading few files from ADLS.
If I read File1. I need to derive/have 4 column transformations
If File 2, then 13 derivations.

I need to use a single parameterized data flow.
Any inputs to achieve this?

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe the same solution as your previous question? hahaha~

Comment: Trying to find other way too :)

Comment: Have you tried using column patterns? Column patterns use metadata functions to find columns you wish to process based on rules.